# How to change background color and color of my layout using scss depending on some conditions in angular?

Tags: sass, angular6

I have a scss file with themes

```
$themes: (
  light: (
    backgroundColor: #fff,
    textColor: #408bbd,     
  ),
  dark: (
    backgroundColor: #222,
    textColor: #ddd,        
  ),    
  taxi: (
    backgroundColor:yellow,
    textColor:black,          
  ),
);
```

I want to switch between them on click of some conditions which I check in my typescript file. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can not access .scss variables in your typescript file but you can access class names.
So, I would suggest you to change these scss variables into classes and you can switch between them using **[ngClass]** attribute depending on whatever condition you want.

Link for reference: 
https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass